# UIO for PC interfacing

Tags: ubuntu, x86, interrupt

I am facing a problem while implementing the UIO technique to handle interrupt in user space.
On my PC  i am running standarad  UBuntu. On  ISA slot i have connected one of the IRQ line with external microcontroller.I want to handle the interrupt in user space as per UIO technique.
However , I dont understand how the uio directory will appear in /dev  folder. The articles about UIO says that to modify the device tree . however on PC there is no device tree . 
So can anybody suggest any idea ?

Comment: You have an ISA slot on a PC running standard Ubuntu?  Do some programs fail to start with SIGILL from trying to use SSE2, assuming your CPUs is older than Pentium 4.  I'm curious what actual hardware you're running.

Comment: I am using SBC which has an ISA slot. I used the term PC in order to avoid any confusion. As everything on SBC and PC is same.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that stuff like http://www.advantech.com/products/single-board-computers/sub_871df718-627e-4240-b94a-30a25c31ce6f existed with an ISA slot + somewhat-modern CPU.  How old is the CPU?